# Get content of GridView

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

I have an application C#/WPF with a ListView containing a GridView. I want to get the content to create a CSV file with all values.

I have made some research to do that but I only found solution for windows form or WPF DataGrid. Nothing for GridView.

My List:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="myListView" 
          BorderBrush="White" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=myItem}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ActualItem}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView x:Name="myGridView">  

            <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.NAME}"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name,Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                            Width="{StaticResource doubleNaN}"/>

            <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.LABEL}"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Label,Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I can get the header but no the content:

```
System.Text.StringBuilder csv = new System.Text.StringBuilder();                        
String separator = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator;

foreach (System.Windows.Controls.GridViewColumn col in myGridView.Columns)
{
    string header = col.Header as String;
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(header))
    {
        csv.Append(header + separator);
    }
}
csv.AppendLine();

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, csv.ToString());
```

How can I get the content to make my CSV file ?

Comment: You're populating the ListView with something called `myItem`. Just iterate through that. That's where the content lives. Also, if you want to add the content to the file, you'll have to write code that does that. All you're adding now is column headers.

Comment: I can get the list `myItem` but the `GridView` display not all properties. If all element from `myItem` have null or empty `NAME`, my `GridViewColumn` doesn't display (width = 0), user can also set width to 0. That why I want to get value from the `GridView` , to get only the displayed value

Comment: So there's some trivial logic you need to reproduce. So reproduce it. The purpose of a GridView isn't to format values for your CSV file. Trying to use it that way is bad design. Specifically, tangling up UI controls with business logic is a classic anti-pattern that WPF and MVVM were invented in large part to steer you away from. I'm tempted to bet money that this code is in an event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, maybe not the best but it works.

The problem was:

- to get header from GridView, because headers depend on language
- to get only displayed columns

Items in GridView are tyep `MyItem` and columns contain properties. I created a loop to get header and property binded by it from `GridView`. A second loop get values from objects properties in `ListView`

```
System.Text.StringBuilder csv = new System.Text.StringBuilder();                        
String separator = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator;
List<String> listProperties = new List<string>();

csv.AppendLine("sep=" + separator);

foreach (System.Windows.Controls.GridViewColumn col in myGridView.Columns)
{

    // Check if column is displayed
    if (col.ActualWidth > 0)
    {
        // Get Header value
        string header = col.Header as String;

        //Check if Header is not empty
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(header))
        {
            // Write in firte line
            csv.Append(header + separator);

            // Get if columns is binding a property
            System.Windows.Data.Binding binding = col.DisplayMemberBinding as System.Windows.Data.Binding;
            if (binding != null)
            {
                // Get the name of property
                listProperties.Add(binding.Path.Path);
            }
        }
    }
}
// Write first line
csv.AppendLine();

foreach (myItem item in myListView.Items)
{
    foreach (String property in listProperties)
    {
        // Get and write value for property
        object value = GetPropValue(item, property);
        csv.Append(value + separator);
    }
    csv.AppendLine();
}

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, csv.ToString());



public static object GetPropValue(object src, string propName)
{
    return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
}
```